# How do I process all php data before returning to the user?

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework

I use zend framework and I have enabled layout on it. Sometimes some bad coded controller/actions may throw an error/warning such as: "Warning: something wrong here in /path/to/controllers/controllername.php on line 12". I wonder if there´s a single point of output that returns the data to the requester, so that I can check what is being sent before sending it. This way I could use a regular expression and remove php warnings from the final result I send to the requester.

Answer (score 2):

When generating a ZF project it creates a errorcontroller which is then set to be used if any exceptions are not catched. this controller also has a view attached to it where you can specify what you want to be displayed when an error occurs.

I'm not sure if its a setting to use the controller or if the framework uses it if it exists, but maybe thats in the documentation.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.exceptions.html#zend.controller.exceptions.handling

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to re-parse the output you can turn off logging errors to the output and/or changing the error reporting level.

You can change the php.ini directly or use the ini_set method.

```
error_reporting( 0 ); // Reporting is off 
error_reporting( E_ALL ); // Reports all
error_reporting( E_ERROR ); // Reports only errors
error_reporting( E_ERROR | E_WARNING ); // Reports errors and warnings
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL ); // Reporting is on
ini_set("error_reporting", 0 ); // Reporting is off

ini_set("display_errors", 0); // Turn off logging to output
ini_set("log_errors", 1); // Turn on logging to file
ini_set("error_log", "errors.log" ); // Name of error log
```